# How to program a button to export table layout to image or PDF file on android app

Tags: android, eclipse, image, export

I feel like I've looked everywhere and I still don't know how to accomplish my goal.  I have an android app that I made with Eclipse, and it has a table layout within a linear layout.  The table does some calculations and provides answers like an excel spreadsheet.  The link to my app is below.  I simply want to add a button to export to an image file that can be stored on the SD drive, that, or a PDF file.  I thought it would be simple, but I'm completely lost here.  I am new to programming, but the app has close to 500 downloads now, and I've had a request to add this function.  I made the activity display in XML.  Thanks for helping.
![enter image description here][1]

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bestserialdilutioncalculator&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5iZXN0c2VyaWFsZGlsdXRpb25jYWxjdWxhdG9yIl0.

So I already have the button made in XML (JPEGB), as you can see further below. In Java code I haven't yet added anything related to this button or to the exporting to image.  The "Button Calculate" is for a different purpose, and is referred to later on in the code.  So basically, this is starting from scratch in the Java code, with a simple button made in XML.  I truncated the code where I considered it unnecessary for this post.  Thanks so much!!

Java Code

```
package com.example.bestserialdilutioncalculator;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.bestserialdilutioncalculator.R;



public class InitialLayout extends Activity {

Button Calculate;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_calculator);
```

XML for Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <View
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/customicon"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        ></View>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CalculateButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/goodbutton"
        android:text=" " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/JPEGB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/jpegbutton"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollerForTable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#000000" >

  <HorizontalScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollerForTable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000">

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/Table"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >
```

rest of code is table layout details, and is very long.

Answer (score 2):

So, you can capture your application's view (screen) and write it to a file.

First create a `Bitmap` of your application's root view:

```
mRootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRootView.getDrawingCache());
mRootView.setDrawingCacheDisabled(false);
```

`mRootView` would be the view you passed into setContentView() in your activity's onCreate() method.

Then write it to disk:

```
// This should be done off the main (UI) thread!
String externalStoragePath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
outFile = new File(externalStoragePath, "myfilename.jpg");

try {
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle error here
}
```

For brevity I have not included the necessary checks for ensuring that external storage is indeed available and mounted. I can add if needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused.  I just taught myself some programming for the first time over a few weeks, and I'm just happy I got the app working.  I tried following your instructions, but I'm lost.  I was about the paste my code into here but I noticed that there is a limit on characters.  I basically have a TableLayout in XML that I would like to convert to Bitmap once a calculation is made.  When the calculation is made, the values in the table change, and those values are what I would like to make an image.  I don't even know how to begin.  Where can I paste my code here to show you?

Comment: Just edit your answer and add the code that you'd like to include. Secondly, this code will create a JPEG of what is currently onscreen. So it could live in an OnClickListener for a button named "Take Screenshot" (or similar).

Comment: I added the code in my original question.  I should also mention that the table that I need to export as an image is larger than most physical screen sizes, and that's why the table is scrollable.  Therefore, I'm concerned that some of the table will be cropped off when the image is created.  Is there a way to export the entire table to an image, or will your code indeed do this?  Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you probably don't want to export a screen shot of your table since it can be bigger than the screen.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It's not a small problem to solve. You could possibly traverse the table's rows and draw their views into one bitmap that you then compress into a JPEG and store on the sd card.

Comment: I think instead I'm going to take the raw values resulting from the calculations and program a CSV table to be generated from those, and completely avoid dealing with the actual screen image.

Comment: That is probably your best bet. Then the user can decide what program to use to view the CSV, generate graphs, etc.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  Do you have any idea how to proceed with the CSV?  I'm going to look around the internet for a thorough guide on that.